# Does a GraphQL Interface definition bind its implementing types to using the same input argument "signature"?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, graphql

For example, the GitHub API declares a type called `Actor`:

```
interface Actor {

    avatarUrl(size: Int): URI!

    login: String!

    resourcePath: URI!

    url: URI!
}
```

1. Is it safe to assume that each type which implements `Actor` takes an `Int` input argument for the field `avatarUrl`?
2. Can a subtype of `Actor` declare more input arguments on the `avatarUrl` field?

This is for a transpiler for the schema language (client implementation), so I don't want to make any assumptions which can fail at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as GraphQL.js is concerned:

1. Yes, any type that implements the `Actor` interface will need to include the `size` argument on its `avatarUrl` field in the type definition.

   To be clear, if the argument is not-NonNull, a client could still leave it off inside a query. However, it will always need to be included in the type definition or GraphQL will complain.
2. Yes, the type implementing `Actor` could declare additional arguments on the field beyond what the Interface mandates. I imagine this would be something of an edge case, as these arguments would not be usable on any queries returning the interface. But a query returning the specific type, not the interface, could technically utilize the additional arguments.

Comment: Thanks. Makes things complicated for #2, my generated kotlin type hierarchy binds an inherited abstract property (on the interface) with a generic argument for the input argument types. Doable, but I'll have to add another level of inheritance in codegen, I think